# Windows automatically created a new System Partition after System partition was full

Tags: windows, windows-10, partitioning, filesystems, disk-space

Preamble: *My drive is divided into two partitions: the **System** one (**C**) and the **Data** one (**D**), plus the other classic windows System Reserved ones (not visible from the explorer). I use Windows 10.*

Lately, my System partition (**C**) was completely full (down to under 1 Mo of free space at some point). So to survive, Windows 10 created a new partition (drive letter **E**) called **System Partition**, I imagine to store the bare minimum to function.

Now I cleared the mess and the classical System (**C**) partition has enough space to function correctly (over 15 Go). However the System Partition that it created (**E**) is still here.

How can I get rid of it without compromising my Windows install ?
I considered merging the two (**C** and **E**) but I'm afraid this will has unintended side effects.
Surprisingly enough I have not been able to find any report of this behaviour on the Internet.

Comment: Please update your question to indicate which build of Windows 10 you are using.  When you provide that information, a screenshot of your current partition layout, would be appreciated.  This information is vital, and answering your question with this information provided, will result in a better answer.

Comment: You are mistaken - Windows does not create partitions on the fly when there is not enough space, it just dies ungracefully.

Comment: Unfortunately the partition is no longer there so I cannot make a full diagnostic of that but what do you think created the partition ? I have seen that for previous Windows versions it doesn't create a partition (https://blog.superuser.com/2012/02/17/wtfriday-what-happens-when-windows-runs-out-of-disk-space/) but for newer OS like Windows 10 I could not find anything. Do you have any source on that ?

Answer (score 0):

I had already restarted my computer multiple times but Windows still had some updates to completely roll-out. After completing all updates (April 2018 Update) and rebooting, Windows deleted the E System Partition on its own.